# How to find all the indexes of a keyword in String

Tags: scala

For example:

If the String is `"provided a provided"` and the keyword is `"provided"`
then the result should be an array contains `[0, 11]`

But if the keyword is `"provide"`
then the result should be an array contains `[-1]`

I tried something like this:

```
val it = "\\bprovided\\b".r.findAllIn("provided a provided");
while (it.hasNext) {
   println(it.next())
}
```

It just print(I need index here)

```
provided
provided
```

How to do this? Which methods I need to use?

Comment: What should be returned for "providede"?

Comment: @om-nom-nom should be an array contains [-1], must be exact keyword

Comment: You have to specify which separators are allowed in this string. What should be returned if input="provided,provided"

Comment: @rtruszk should be [0,9]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> val it = "\\bprovided\\b".r.findAllMatchIn("provided a provided")
it: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> if (it.isEmpty) List(-1) else it.map(_.start).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 11)
```

Comment: not work when I type these codes in Eclipse IDE. Error msg:
`Multiple markers at this line
 - value start is not a member of 
  String
 - value start is not a member of 
  String`

Comment: @CSnerd: You'll need to use `.findAllMatchIn`, not `.findAllIn`.